# Jinja Extension that has access to Context

Tags: python, jinja2

Is it possible to write a Jinja2 Extension that, while rendering, has access to the template context? I want to write an extension that accesses a context variable and outputs some data based on that variable. I couldn't find enough information on how to write such an extension.

Right now, I have this:

```
class CsrfExtension(jinja2.ext.Extension):
    r""" Adds a {% csrf %} tag to Jinja. """

    tags = set(['csrf'])
    template = '<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="%s">'

    def parse(self, parser):
        token = next(parser.stream)
        lineno = token.lineno
        return self.call_method('_render_csrf', lineno=lineno)

    def _render_csrf(self, value, name, *args, **kwargs):
        csrf_token = somehow_get_variable('csrf_token')
        return jinja2.Markup(self.template % csrf_token)
```

But, in `foo.jinja`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a Test</h1>
        {% csrf %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I get

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (foo.jinja, line 7)
```

I thought I'd get a NameError since `somehow_get_variable()` is not defined. I need to know a) how to get the variable from the current context, and b) how to write the Extension correctly.

Also, why line 7? The `{% csrf %}` tag is on line 5. Even when I trim `foo.jinja` to have only one line with the `{% csrf %}` tag in it, it says line 7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it. Seems like Jinja generates Python code from the Jinja AST (?) and that conversion failed, therefore caused the SyntaxError. `jinja2.nodes.ContextReference()` can be used to get the render Context.

```
class CsrfExtension(jinja2.ext.Extension):
    r""" Adds a {% csrf %} tag to Jinja. """

    tags = set(['csrf', 'csrf_token'])
    template = u'<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="%s">'

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        ctx_ref = jinja2.nodes.ContextReference()
        node = self.call_method('_render_csrf', [ctx_ref], lineno=lineno)
        return jinja2.nodes.CallBlock(node, [], [], [], lineno=lineno)

    def _render_csrf(self, context, caller):
        csrf_token = context['csrf_token']
        return jinja2.Markup(self.template % unicode(csrf_token))

csrf = CsrfExtension
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and I found the solution to be decorating the call method with the `@contextfunction` decorator.  That tells the runtime to pass the active context as a first argument to the call method.

```
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension
from jinja2.utils import contextfunction


class MyExtension(Extension):
    """See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/extensions/#module-jinja2.ext
    for more information on how to create custom Jinja extensions.
    """
    tags = set(['myext'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(MyExtension, self).__init__(environment)

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno

        # Parse args if you need them ...
        # args = [parser.parse_expression()]

        node = nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method('_myext_method', args),
                               [], [], []).set_lineno(lineno)
        return parser.parse_import_context(node, True)

    @contextfunction
    def _myext_method(self, context, args, caller):
        # Return what you need
        return "Hello I am a custom extension, rendered with: %r" % context
```